# Why does $x/(x^2+4)$ have a range?

Tags: functions

The domain of this graph is all real numbers. There are no vertical asymptotes but there is a horizontal one at $y=0$. But then when I graph there's an $x$ value at $y=0$ and there is a range (where $-a\le y\le a$). Usually I would find an inverse of $f(x)$ to figure out the range of $f(x)$ but this graph has no inverse since it's not $1:1$

Comment: if $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+4}$, find $f(0)$. Also, see [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%2F(x%5E2%2B4)&t=crmtb01).

Comment: If there is a range, there is an absolute max and min of the function. Do you know of a way to use derivatives to find maxes and mins?

Comment: yes there's an absolute max and min of the function, i used google and it's around y=-.25 and .25 at x=-2 and 2. i've tried useing WolframAlpha and it doesn't work, it didn't give me the range. and no, i don't know how to use derivatives to find max and mins

Answer (score 3):

For $x > 0,$
$$  (x-2)^2 \geq 0,  $$
$$ x^2 - 4 x + 4 \geq 0,  $$
$$  x^2 + 4 \geq 4 x,  $$
$$ 4 x \leq x^2 + 4,  $$
$$  \frac{4x}{x^2 + 4} \leq 1,  $$
$$    \frac{x}{x^2 + 4} \leq \frac{1}{4} $$

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU <3 thank you <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

It has a range becuase it has a domain.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the derivative approach here is the thing :

$f(-x) = -f(x) $ so if you find the max point for positive $x$ you can find the min for negativs.

and we know that the maximum of $f(x)$ must be between 0 and 1 because in other parts of the positive numbers, $f(x)$ value gets smaller as $x$ gets bigger . so now you have a $1:1$ function for $0<x<1$ and you can find the *inverse* and do it your way. but it's better to use other ways like derivative.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a good qualitative understanding of what the graph of the function $f(x)=x/(x^2+4)$ looks like:  It starts at $0$, rises to some maximum, and then falls asymptotically back to $0$ for positive $x$, and symmetrically with a negative minimum for negative $x$.  If you can figure out what the maximum value is -- let's call it $M$ -- then the range is $[-M,M]$.

If $f(x)$ takes a value $M\gt0$, then we have

$$M={x\over x^2+4}\implies Mx^2-x+4M=0\implies x={1\pm\sqrt{1-16M^2}\over2M}$$

which implies the expression inside the square root is non-negative, i.e. $1-16M^2\ge0$.  This leads to $M=1/4$ as the largest value $f(x)$ can take.